# i have 800x600 resolution on my video card. How to see video with mplayer and video with AVC 1024 x 552

Tags: mplayer

Is there any way to see that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file for playback and hit <kbd>f</kbd>. The video will run in full screen mode and downscale to your current resolution.

Comment: this is not true